# SSIS and sending out Email List from variable with expressions

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I created and SSIS package that is emailing out a report.  I would like to populate the *TO* field in the Send Mail Task Editor with a list of emails.  I have a single row of emails separated by semicolons that I want to place into the *ToLine* expression. I have created a variable @[User::EmailList] that is a string but when I try to populate the *ToLine* nothing happens and I get an error saying that the ToLine cannot be blank. I know I am getting values back because I created a simple script task that displays a msgbox with the requested string. All I am looking for is a way to populate the ToLine with dynamically created string of less that 4000 characters. Thanks

FYI-This in on a 64-bit SQL 2005 server

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using the send mail task? In this case you go to theexpressions tab. Pick the property of ToLine and then set the expression to be equal to the variable where you are storing the To information.